# How can I change each div id which is the last part of a number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to change each div id with change function.

before:

```
<div id="a_1">a1</div>
<div id="b_1">b1</div>
<div id="c_1">c1</div>
<div id="d_1">d1</div>
<button onclick="change()">Değiştir</button>
```

after:

```
<div id="a_2">a2</div>
<div id="b_2">b2</div>
<div id="c_2">c2</div>
<div id="d_2">d2</div>
<button onclick="change()">Değiştir</button>
```

I've tried this function but it didnt work

```
function change()
{ 
    var old_id=1;
    var new_id=2;
    alert( bas( $("#a_1").attr("id")) );
    $("div[id$=_"+old_id+"]").attr("id",  bas(  $("div[id$=_"+old_id+"]").attr("id")   ) +new_id);
}
```

How can I do?
Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need this? Using incremental `id` attributes always leads to maintenance issues like this. Is there a reason you don't use a common `class` instead?

Comment: do you want to increment the div's id every time while clicking the change() function?

Comment: He might be using numbers just as an example to simplify the question, it's not necessarily incementing.

Comment: I know but there is already a complex structure and I dont want to change it. This is just an example

Comment: What does the function `bas` do?

Comment: bas func returns a_ when put a_1. But the change func. is changing all div id as a_2 when I use

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have added `class` attribute to the `div` elements. Here is the demo [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/3LWzT/2/)

HTML:

```
<div id="a_1" class="my_div">a1</div>
<div id="b_1" class="my_div">b1</div>
<div id="c_1" class="my_div">c1</div>
<div id="d_1" class="my_div">d1</div>
<button onclick="change_ids()">Değiştir</button>
```

JS:

```
change_ids=function()
{
    var old_id=1;
    var new_id=2;

    $('div.my_div').each(function() {
        var div_id = $(this).attr('id');
        var arr = div_id.split("_");
        //alert(arr[0]+" "+arr[1]);
        var new_div_id = arr[0]+"_"+new_id;
        $(this).attr('id', new_div_id);
        $(this).html(new_div_id);
    });
    alert('Div ids changed')
}
```

Comment: Thanx for answer. It works, but each div s has a separate class. I have not to change class.

Comment: so where is the problem ? div elements can have multiple classes ! In your existing code if you already have some class for the div elements, then you can add one more to it separated by a space.

Comment: Yes I've add a second class oto divs and it's working now. Thank you so much

Comment: Then you should accept my answer as a correct answer !! :)   Because it can help may other users to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some small changes you can achieve these this easily.

Try this:

HTML Code:

```
<div id="a_1">a1</div>
<div id="b_1">b1</div>
<div id="c_1">c1</div>
<div id="d_1">d1</div>
<button onclick="change(1, 2)">Değiştir</button>
```

Javascript/Jquery Code:

```
function change(oldid, newid)
{   
    $('div[id $= "_' +oldid+ '"]').each(function(){
      var clone =$(this).clone(true).attr('id' , 'id_' + newid);
        $('body').append(clone);
    });
    var nextid = newid + 1;
    $('body').append('<button onclick="change(' + newid + ',' + nextid +')">Değiştir</button>');
}
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/8EzV8/1/)